# LWJGL3 - can't render triangle but can clear color

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I've been trying to render a triangle on my screen for the past day but I can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly. The only thing that works is displaying a window and rendering to it using clear color. Does anyone know what I'm doing incorrectly? All I'm expecting is to see a black triangle rendered on screen like I've done once in the past but currently I'm not able to do that.

Here's the code:

Main:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello");
        // Create Window
        Window.createWindow();
        long window = Window.getWindow();
        // Create Renderer
        Renderer renderer = new Renderer();
        // Data
        float[] positions = {
                0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
        };
        // Create Model
        Model triangle = Loader.dataToModel(positions);
        // Render on window
        while(!GLFW.glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
            GLFW.glfwPollEvents();
            renderer.clear();
            renderer.render(triangle);

            GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(window);   // !@#!@#!@# remember to add!!!  !@#!@# Order important prob
        }
        System.out.println("TERMINATED");
        Window.terminateWindow();
    }
}
```

Window:

```java
public class Window {
    private static long window;
    private static Callback debugCallback;

    public static void createWindow(){
        // Creates a window

        // Init
        if(!GLFW.glfwInit()){
            throw new IllegalStateException("ERROR: could not GLFW.glfwInit()");
        }

        // Hints
        // Hint opengl version
        GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR,3);
        GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR,2);
        // Hint compatibility (profile, forward compat)
        GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT,GLFW.GLFW_TRUE);
        // Hint to hide initially
        GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_VISIBLE,GLFW.GLFW_FALSE);
        // Hint debug
        GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_DEBUG_CONTEXT, GLFW.GLFW_TRUE);


        // Actually create window
        window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(500, 500, "thinMatrix4", 0, 0);
        if(window == 0){
            throw new IllegalStateException("ERROR: during GLFW.glfwCreateWindow");
        }

        // Context and Capabilities
        GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);    // create context for window
        GL.createCapabilities();    // find all the opengl stuff to give capabilities

        // Debugging enable
        GL11.glEnable(org.lwjgl.opengl.KHRDebug.GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);
        debugCallback = GLUtil.setupDebugMessageCallback();

        // Position window
        GLFWVidMode vidMode = GLFW.glfwGetVideoMode(GLFW.glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        GLFW.glfwSetWindowPos(window,vidMode.width()/2,vidMode.height()/2);

        // Window show
        GLFW.glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    public static void terminateWindow(){
        // Termination
        GLFW.glfwTerminate();
    }

    // GETTERS
    public static long getWindow() {
        return window;
    }
}
```

Renderer:

```java
public class Renderer {
    public void render(Model model){
        // Enable to allow model rendering
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVAO());
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        // Render
        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES,model.getVertexCount(),0);
        // Clean up
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
    public void clear(){
        GL11.glClearColor(0f,0.8f,.6f,1f);
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
}
```

Model:

```java
public class Model {
    private int vertexCount;
    private int vao;
    public Model(int vao, int count){
        this.vao = vao;
        this.vertexCount = count;
    }
    // GETTERS
    public int getVertexCount(){
        return this.vertexCount;
    }
    public int getVAO(){ return this.vao; }
}
```

```java
public class Loader {
    private static List<Integer> vaos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static List<Integer> vbos = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static Model dataToModel(float[] data){
        // Create VAO
        int vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
        vaos.add(vao);

        // Create Buffer (VBO) for actual data
        int vbo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,toFloatBuffer(data), GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);      //!@#!@#!@# What happens if data is not a float buffer
        // vertex attribute pointer
        GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(0,3, GL11.GL_FLOAT,false,0,0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
        vbos.add(vbo);

        // Create model
        int count = data.length/3;
        Model model = new Model(vao, count);
        return model;
    }
    private static FloatBuffer toFloatBuffer(float[] data){
        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length);
        buffer.put(data);
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the `java` bindings but your call to `GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(0,3, GL11.GL_FLOAT,false,0,0)` appears to specify a zero length stride.  I would expects to see something like `GL30.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 12, 0)`.

Comment: I tried that just in case but sadly it didn't fix my issue.

Comment: @G.M. It is valid to specify a stride of 0. In this case stride is assumed to be the `size * sizeof(type)`.

Comment: You've requested a Core context, where are your shaders?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Indeed, forgot about that.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) incorrectly. The 2nd argument is the index of the 1st vertex to be rendered and the 3rd argument is the number of vertices:

<s>`GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES,model.getVertexCount(),0);`</s>

```java
GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model.getVertexCount());
```